# Simple mod_rewrite rules broken after new c9 version

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cloud9-ide

I'm working on a project hosted on the [Cloud9 IDE](http://c9.io). I had a simple set of mod_rewrite rules set up, but they no longer work after c9's new version rollout. It took me forever to iron out these rules (I'm a novice at best at this) I'm confused as to why these rules no longer work (AFAIK, the new c9 version should not have affected mod_rewrite rules).

Here are the rules (located in the root `.htaccess`)

```
RewriteEngine on
Options FollowSymLinks

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/css/.*$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/img/.*$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/js/.*$
RewriteCond Astralis/resources%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ Astralis/resources/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

The goal is pretty straightforward... All requests going to `/css/...` `/img/...` or `/js/...` should serve up the associated file within `Astralis/resources` (after checking that the file exists). Otherwise, redirect the rest of the traffic to index.php.

The problem I am experiencing is that all requests to resources (css, img, js) are returning 404's. If I move the /css, /img, and /js folders from within Astralis/resources back to the root directory, all the resources load properly. This problem started happening after c9's new version, with no changes to the .htaccess file, the codebase, or directory structure.

Any clue as to what is going on? How do I debug this kind of stuff? Any general tips/tricks for writing mod_rewrite rules would also be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Apache needs full path of the file in order to return true using `-f` you will need to use `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/` before your file path.

Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options FollowSymLinks

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(css|img|js)/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/Astralis/resources%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ Astralis/resources/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: The requests are returning 500's now

Comment: Even if I take out the line that checks to see if the resource exists, I still get 500's

Comment: Can you check your Apache error.log to see what is the actual error.

Comment: Good Idea -- The error appears to be coming from within another .htaccess inside Astralis/resources. /home/ubuntu/workspace/Astralis/resources/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Comment: Here is the contents of that .htaccess:  <FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|less)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "no-cache"
</FilesMatch>

Comment: So `Header` directive is not recognized. Looks like `mod_headers` is not enabled in your Apache config.

Comment: That was the case, @anubhava. It appears ubuntu has mod_headers disabled by default. Had to enable it manually and restart apache